# isNewBar() not producing the right time Stochastic value onTick MQL5

Tags: c#, mql5, metatrader5

Check this program I am trying to get the values of the `Stochastic`

```
#include <Lib CisNewBar.mqh>

CisNewBar current_chart; // instance of the CisNewBar class:
                         //                 detect new tick candlestick

void OnTick()
{
     if (  current_chart.isNewBar() >  0 )
     {
           int stoch = iStochastic(_Symbol,PERIOD_M1,5,3,3,MODE_SMA,STO_LOWHIGH);
           double K[],D[];
           ArraySetAsSeries(K,true);
           ArraySetAsSeries(D,true);
           CopyBuffer(stoch,0,0,5,K);
           CopyBuffer(stoch,1,0,5,D);
           ArrayPrint(K);
     }
}
```

Here is the output I got:

```
95.97315 90.40000 74.11765 49.25373 25.00000
73.68421 81.87919 90.40000 74.11765 49.25373
74.34211 80.70175 81.87919 90.40000 74.11765
90.24390 78.94737 80.70175 81.87919 90.40000
78.33333 84.05797 78.94737 80.70175 81.87919
```

The above values represents Array elements as `0th, 1st,2nd,3rd & 4th`
What is the `0th` in the initial print will become the previous for the next and will be placed at the `1st` position in the next print.
But I see the values has changed and is drastic.

Previously the `iStochastic()` was giving the right and correct values. But it was working `OnTick()` and hence was giving the output for every change. I only need the values when the bar is complete or after minute. So, I tried the solution from the community. Here is the link: [solution for newbar](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/159)

But the output is infront and is changing the equation of my trade which is why I am losing it.

Please help me. How I can make it work for me?

Here are the files needed: [Lib CisNewBar.mqh](https://jpst.it/1cY3q)

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Lib CisNewBar.mqh |
//| Copyright 2010, Lizar |
//| Lizar-2010@mail.ru |
//| Revision 2010.09.27 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Class CisNewBar. |
//| Appointment: Class with methods of detecting new bars |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+

class CisNewBar
{
protected:
datetime m_lastbar_time; // Time of opening last bar

string m_symbol; // Symbol name
ENUM_TIMEFRAMES m_period; // Chart period

uint m_retcode; // Result code of detecting new bar
int m_new_bars; // Number of new bars
string m_comment; // Comment of execution

public:
void CisNewBar(); // CisNewBar constructor
//--- Methods of access to protected data:
uint GetRetCode() const {return(m_retcode); } // Result code of detecting new bar
datetime GetLastBarTime() const {return(m_lastbar_time);} // Time of opening new bar
int GetNewBars() const {return(m_new_bars); } // Number of new bars
string GetComment() const {return(m_comment); } // Comment of execution
string GetSymbol() const {return(m_symbol); } // Symbol name
ENUM_TIMEFRAMES GetPeriod() const {return(m_period); } // Chart period
//--- Methods of initializing protected data:
void SetLastBarTime(datetime lastbar_time){m_lastbar_time=lastbar_time; }
void SetSymbol(string symbol) {m_symbol=(symbol==NULL || symbol=="")?Symbol():symbol; }
void SetPeriod(ENUM_TIMEFRAMES period) {m_period=(period==PERIOD_CURRENT)?Period():period; }
//--- Methods of detecting new bars:
bool isNewBar(datetime new_Time); // First type of request for new bar
int isNewBar(); // Second type of request for new bar
};

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| CisNewBar constructor. |
//| INPUT: no. |
//| OUTPUT: no. |
//| REMARK: no. |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CisNewBar::CisNewBar()
{
m_retcode=0; // Result code of detecting new bar
m_lastbar_time=0; // Time of opening last bar
m_new_bars=0; // Number of new bars
m_comment=""; // Comment of execution
m_symbol=Symbol(); // Symbol name, by default - symbol of current chart
m_period=Period(); // Chart period, by default - period of current chart
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| First type of request for new bar |
//| INPUT: newbar_time - time of opening (hypothetically) new bar|
//| OUTPUT: true - if new bar(s) has(ve) appeared |
//| false - if there is no new bar or in case of error |
//| REMARK: no. |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
bool CisNewBar::isNewBar(datetime newbar_time)
{
//--- Initialization of protected variables
m_new_bars = 0; // Number of new bars
m_retcode = 0; // Result code of detecting new bar: 0 - no error
m_comment =__FUNCTION__+" Successful check for new bar";
//---

//--- Just to be sure, check: is the time of (hypothetically) new bar m_newbar_time less than time of last bar m_lastbar_time?
if(m_lastbar_time>newbar_time)
{ // If new bar is older than last bar, print error message
m_comment=__FUNCTION__+" Synchronization error: time of previous bar "+TimeToString(m_lastbar_time)+
", time of new bar request "+TimeToString(newbar_time);
m_retcode=-1; // Result code of detecting new bar: return -1 - synchronization error
return(false);
}
//---

//--- if it's the first call
if(m_lastbar_time==0)
{
m_lastbar_time=newbar_time; //--- set time of last bar and exit
m_comment =__FUNCTION__+" Initialization of lastbar_time = "+TimeToString(m_lastbar_time);
return(false);
}
//---

//--- Check for new bar:
if(m_lastbar_time<newbar_time)
{
m_new_bars=1; // Number of new bars
m_lastbar_time=newbar_time; // remember time of last bar
return(true);
}
//---

//--- if we've reached this line, then the bar is not new; return false
return(false);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Second type of request for new bar |
//| INPUT: no. |
//| OUTPUT: m_new_bars - Number of new bars |
//| REMARK: no. |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int CisNewBar::isNewBar()
{
datetime newbar_time;
datetime lastbar_time=m_lastbar_time;

//--- Request time of opening last bar:
ResetLastError(); // Set value of predefined variable _LastError as 0.
if(!SeriesInfoInteger(m_symbol,m_period,SERIES_LASTBAR_DATE,newbar_time))
{ // If request has failed, print error message:
m_retcode=GetLastError(); // Result code of detecting new bar: write value of variable _LastError
m_comment=__FUNCTION__+" Error when getting time of last bar opening: "+IntegerToString(m_retcode);
return(0);
}
//---

//---Next use first type of request for new bar, to complete analysis:
if(!isNewBar(newbar_time)) return(0);

//---Correct number of new bars:
m_new_bars=Bars(m_symbol,m_period,lastbar_time,newbar_time)-1;

//--- If we've reached this line - then there is(are) new bar(s), return their number:
return(m_new_bars);
}
```

Comment: How did you initialize it, what is in the OnInit() and what timeframe,symbol in the tester is used? Also looks like you've edited the code from the newbar paper a little. have you checked the original newbar code? Have you tried to copyRates and match time[i] with K[i] or D[i]

Comment: I am using `M1` and `EURUSD` pair in testing. I do not need rates at the moment, what I am trying to achieve is get the values of the stochastic. The value at `0th` position is not what is right, as you see in the output. There is nothing in the `OnInit` I am making it done `OnTick()`. As you see in the program

Comment: @DanielKniaz Where I can find the original code for the isnewBar? Can you get me reference for it for MQL5?

Comment: You provided a link on MQL5.com articles, the original code is there.

Comment: If you do not have OnInit() then your code is not initialized I am afraid. you must initialize it somehow I believe, otherwise it might misunderstand the fields. If you use the rates structure, you would be able to see which stoch is referring to which value, and debug the problem

Comment: Have you check the link I have shared in the question? I guess that is what I am using.

Comment: @DanielKniaz Can you show me the way for debug? I have tried many things and what you are saying is something new to me. Can you help me with that?